# what's easy way to change bg color of tab list in visual composer for wp?

Tags: php, wordpress, tabs

I try to add some css to change the colors for the 4 single box of tab.
Did you know how can i do it simply?

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tab-1422192457610-631b6-1747" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true"><a href="#tab-1422192457610-631b6-1747" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><i class="icon-browser"></i>TURISMO</a></li>
```

[link to sie](http://www.futuracoopsociale.it/borgo-dei-servizi/)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

active + hover tab

```
.vc-icon-tab, .wpb_tabs_nav li.ui-tabs-active, .vc-icon-tab, .wpb_tabs_nav li:hover {
background-color: #110000;
color: #fff;
}
```

other tabs

```
.vc-icon-tab .wpb_tabs_nav li {
color: #474747
background: silver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.home, .ui-tabs-nav, .ui-corner-top {

    background-color:orange;
}

.vc-icon-tab .wpb_tabs_nav li a {

    color:#001100;

}
```